# Disable textbox based on input entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

I have 7 input textboxes.Based on the input enter i need to disable them accordingly.For eg if i enter input as 4 out the first four text boxes should be diabled accordingly(input is restricted to less than 7),and this is to be done using Jquery

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < contract; i++) 
{
    $('#tblTest').find('tbody').find('tr').find('.Year')[i].disabled = false; 
    var samtes = $('#tblTest').find('tbody').find('tr').find('.Year')[0].disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This snippet has performances issues, you may call it micro-optimization, but it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example on how to do that:

```
$("input").on("change", function()
{
    $("input:lt(" + $(this).data("index") + ")").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7dk53cz/).

Using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) I set the index of each element(you can use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) in some cases, but it is more complex). So, when any element is changed I get all inputs with index [less than](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) the changed one (`input:lt(index)`) and *disable* it setting its [property](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) `disabled`.

I hope it is clear.

Comment: dint understand could you be more specific?

Comment: @AlanJacob sorry but what part you didn't get ?